# Gvim Graphical Preview

Tags: vim, emacs, latex, gvim, graphviz

I have seen some videos on YuoTube where people are doing some cool things with Emacs, e.g. [compiling a LaTeX file and viewing it as a pdf from within Emacs](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=BBzvlKtDFmQ). I have also seen a [graphviz DOT file compiled and it's PNG viewed within Emacs](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ZmxEt_OgVpg). Can similar things be done with gvim?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Does it really matter whether the preview is inside Vim or external to it?

Here's what I do. In my .vimrc, I have:

```
" save file whenever cursor moves
function! Update_if_possible()
    if filewritable(bufname("%"))
        update
    endif
endfunction
au CursorMoved * call Update_if_possible()
au CursorMovedI * call Update_if_possible()
```

This causes (g)vim to save the file whenever the cursor moves. In effect, the file is always saved this way.

I use the [latex-box plugin](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=3109) for writing LaTeX, which uses [latexmk](http://www.phys.psu.edu/~collins/software/latexmk-jcc/) to compile. Latexmk can be configured to auto-recompile whenever the file changes.

On the left side of my screen I put the gvim window. On the right side, I put a PDF viewer which auto-reloads whenever the PDF changes. (You can use any of several for linux: evince, okular, zathura, xpdf, etc.) The upshot is that the PDF previewer updates as I type. It's not nearly as fast as, say, [gummi](http://gummi.midnightcoding.org/)'s live preview, but it's pretty close. It's certainly better than the emacs video you linked to, since unlike that, I don't even have to do anything to compile; gvim's constant saving of the file coupled with latexmk means the file is always compiling as I type, and hence, the PDF preview is always updating.

Answer (score 0):

No. Within gvim you can compile a file and display the results with an external viewer in its own window, but not within a gvim window.